# XSLT test whether a XML node contains another XML node?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have been trying to check whether a particular node contains another node inside it, not necessarily as its child but even as child of its child or so on.

For example:

```
<a>
    <c> looking for me?</c>
</a>
```

and

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>looking for me?</c>
    </b>
</a>
```

In the above cases I am looking for a `a` node which contains a `c` node.
In both of the above cases the test should pass because both `a` nodes contain a `c` node.

I thought of using `//c` in each `a`'s context but wouldn't that select all the `c` nodes in the XML rather than the one inside that particular `a`? If yes, can anyone suggest me a way to do it?

Thnx in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer given by @Lingamurthy CS is wrong. `//c` finds `c` elements *anywhere* in the input XML.

Instead use:

```
<xsl:template match="a[descendant::c]">
```

which matches an `a` element if it has a descendant element `c`.

To prove it, assume the following XML input. There is a `c` element, but it is not a descendant of `a`.

**Input XML** (modified)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <a>
   </a>
   <c>wrong</c>
   <a>
      <b>
      </b>
   </a>
</root>
```

**Output** (using @Lingamurthy CS' template)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <yes/>
   wrong
   <yes/>
```

As you can see, `test="exists(//c)"` evaluates to "true" in both cases - which is wrong. No `yes` elements should be output.

On the other hand, using:

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="a[descendant::c]">
      <yes/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the same input I describe above, results in

**Output** (using `descendant::c`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


   wrong
```

No `yes` elements are output. Only the text content of the `c` element is output because of the XSLT processor's default behaviour.

Comment: Well, the template was written only for the input XML, provided by Surender, which has only one 'a' as root node. :)

Comment: I know. That's what I am trying to say. Your solution does not really check whether an `a` element has a descendant `c` element. Rather, it checks whether there are `c` elements _at all_.

Answer (score 1):

Use '//' to skip an arbitrary number of children levels:

```
//a//c
```

Comment: "looking for me?" is just a sample text. It is not present in the actual xml.

Comment: @SurenderThakran, then don't include it in the search pattern (see my last edit)